# How to add a reset() function to a drag and drop HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, reset

Hi I'm trying to implement a reset() function to this drag and drop interface. Initially the bars are arranged in a random order (hardcoded positions) and the user cant move them around by drag/drop. I want a reset function to refresh the div element with the table to its initial positions.

I have tried to copy the innerhtml code and set it again on the reset button click but this method doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way in which this is possible?

```
<script>
var container = document.getElementById("game1");  
var content = container.innerHTML;

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var evtarget=ev.target;
      if (evtarget=="[object HTMLImageElement]"){
           evtarget = evtarget.parentNode;
      }
      else {
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      }
}

function reset1(){
    var container = document.getElementById("game1");
    var content = container.innerHTML;
    alert(content);
    container.innerHTML= content;`
}
```

```
<div id="game1" style="padding-top: 140px; padding-left:40px">
<div class="container1">
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr><td>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag8" src="img/8.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop=""></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag4" src="img/4.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag3" src="img/3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag5" src="img/5.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag1" src="img/1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag7" src="img/7.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag6" src="img/6.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag9" src="img/9.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div9" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag2" src="img/2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag10" src="img/10.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="div11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:230px; padding-top:15px; width:100px;">
           <input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset" onclick="reset1();" style="width:150px; background-color:black; color:white;"> 
        </td></tr>
    </table>
        <br>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which plugin are you using for drag and drop?

Comment: i guess there are no plugins used. I used the basic syntax given in http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

however, jQuery is used to check whether each image is dragged onto the right spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the HTML on load to a global variable and use it when you are clicking `reset` button.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("game1");  
var content = container.innerHTML;

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var evtarget=ev.target;
      if (evtarget=="[object HTMLImageElement]"){
           evtarget = evtarget.parentNode;
      }
      else {
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      }
}

function reset1(){
    var container = document.getElementById("game1");
    container.innerHTML= html;
}                
var html;
window.onload = function(){
 html = document.getElementById('game1').innerHTML;
};
```

```css
.container1 table div{
    width:60px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="game1" style="padding-top: 140px; padding-left:40px">
<div class="container1">
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
       <td><div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag8" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/f00/fff" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop=""></div></td>
        <td><div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag4" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/00f/fff" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div></td>
        <td><div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
        <td><div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
        <td><div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
        <td><div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag7" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/0ff/fff" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div></td>
        <td><div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag6" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/a0f/fff" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div></td>
        <td><div id="div8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag9" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/fb2/fff" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div></td>
        <td><div id="div9" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag2" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/bd6/fff" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div></td>
        <td><div id="div10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img id="drag10" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/12d/fff" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>
        <td><div id="div11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:230px; padding-top:15px; width:100px;">
           <input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset" onclick="reset1();" style="width:150px; background-color:black; color:white;"> 
        </td></tr>
    </table>
        <br>        
    </div>
</div>
```